# Alfresco custom model with sys:base as parent is having property cm:name

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have created a custom model with parent as sys:base and modified the `share-config-custom.xml` so that I can create the content from the share. After creating the content from share am unable to see the content in share or explore. Instead am getting the below error when checking from document details page.

```
The item cannot be found. Either you do not have permissions to view the item, it has been removed or it never existed.
```

In `Node browser` I can see `cm:name` in the property field. But as per the alfresco svn, sys:base is not having the property cm:name.

```
<type name="sys:base">
<title>Base</title>
<mandatory-aspects>
<aspect>sys:referenceable</aspect>
<aspect>sys:localized</aspect>
</mandatory-aspects>
</type>
```

Can someone please tell how the custom model get the cm:name property? 
Also I want to delete the content. Is there any way to delete that content from share or explore?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To delete your content, call the webscript

> /slingshot/doclib/action/aspects/node/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}

and send the `sys:temporary` as an argument.